# Which scheme implementation is easiest to embed into C/C++ program?

Tags: scheme

I am rewriting a program that has embedded a script language for extension and configuration, the old program used Lua, Lua can be embedded into my program easily, just download its source, decompress, and move all source files into my program directory, remove lua.c and luac.c, and everything works very well. For functional programming language learning, I decided to choose a lisp dialect(scheme) as new script backend, but there is a lot of [scheme implemetation](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards#implementations), which one is best for embedding ?

Answer (score 11):

There is a plethora of Schemes made for embedding. Two that I would personally recommend:

- [Chibi](https://code.google.com/p/chibi-scheme/), because it's designed to be small and lightweight and supports the new R7RS standard
- [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), because it's GNU's choice and is a very mature project

Of the two, Chibi works hard to keep its code and memory footprint small. On the other hand, Guile is more advanced in terms of features offered. Only Chibi supports R7RS, but I believe Guile is working towards that.

For a look at the other great Schemes, take a look at [Wikipedia's listing of Scheme implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scheme_implementations).

Comment: Thanks for recommendation ! Guile has many depends, like libgmp, libunistring etc. And they are redundant for me. I decided to try ChibiScheme, it was quickly compiled on my computer.

Comment: Chibi scheme can only compiled under Cygwin on Windows, my MinGW cannot support it.

Comment: @moligaloo i brought up Chibi in Visual Studio on Windows with zero drama, zero warnings, zero commenting out defines and includes (the usual crap when porting to windows), zero errors, and all unit tests passing. Required only running CMake, which produces a Visual Studio .sln file, pressing F7 build all, running the tests project. Five clicks and less than one minute from download to working code.

Comment: wikipedia link moved to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scheme_(programming_language)_implementations

Answer (score 7):

I know it's a really old question, but check out s7 scheme:
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/snd/snd/s7.html

It's distributed as a tarball containing just s7.h and s7.c, which is exactly what you wanted for easy embedding.  Plus it has a nice amount of features, some even unique to s7.

Comment: in the simple .h + .c deployment, apparently new contender Janet can do this as well: https://janet-lang.org/, if you like more of the clojure-y feel to your scheme

Answer (score 5):

I recommend trying [Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/fp/Bigloo/). From their website:

> Bigloo is a Scheme implementation devoted to one goal: enabling Scheme based programming style where C(++) is usually required. Bigloo attempts to make Scheme practical by offering features usually presented by traditional programming languages but not offered by Scheme and functional programming. Bigloo compiles Scheme modules. It delivers small and fast stand alone binary executables. Bigloo enables full connections between Scheme and C programs, between Scheme and Java programs, and between Scheme and C# programs.

I have seen it used successfully in production for embedding scheme into a C application. A major advantage of Bigloo over other projects is that it supports fully-compiled scheme code. And of course you can mix that with interpreted scheme code as needed.